# How to show $\lim_{x\to -3} x^2=9$ by $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition

Tags: calculus

by $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition

Show $\lim_{x\to -3} x^2=9$

Attempt:

take: $\delta=1$. So $-1\lt x+3\lt 1$ implies $-7\lt x-3 \lt -5$

$|x^2-9|=|x+3||x-3|\lt |x+3|.7$

Hence, let $\delta=\epsilon /7$

our delta is :$\delta=\min\lbrace 1,\epsilon/7 \rbrace$

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/7\}$, then if $\vert x+3\vert<\delta\le\epsilon/7$, by the preceding discussion, $\vert x-3\vert<7$ and hence
$$\vert x^2-9\vert=\vert x+3\vert\vert x-3\vert
  <\left(\frac{\epsilon}{7}\right)\cdot7=\epsilon.$$